# I want to know why Redis use key-value for storing?

Tags: redis

I am studying Redis and I want to know why Redis use key-value for storing?
and why use Redis there is SQL which is key-value then why not SQL why Redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQL vs Redis:**

SQL is a database technology which persists data onto disk whereas Redis a cache store i.e. it stores data on RAM. 
Since RAM access is faster than DISK access, storing and fetching data in Redis is much faster than SQL but the catch is RAM has limited storage. 
So basically, one might want to store some part of data into Redis so as to make the application faster.

**Redis is Key-Value:**

Generally, some part of the data is frequently accessed whereas some is not. One again might want to store this particular field into Redis and rest into SQL database.

Redis is used so as to make the application faster by reducing the number of hits to the DISK.